# Python: how to memory-map(mmap) a gzipped file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, mmap

My requirement is to read a gzipped file and since these files will be huge, I would like to memory-map it to gain I/O performance.

I tried following code:

```
import gzip
import mmap
with gzip.open("/home/test.json.gz", mode="r") as f:
    with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as f_mmap:
        print(f_mmap.read())
```

The `print` statement from the above code prints series of the following such hex as output:

```
b'\x1f\x8b
```

When I tried removing the `mmap` from the above code, I see the correct expected result.

Could you please help with suggestions on how to memory-map a gzipped file?

Answer (score 5):

`mmap` is *raw* file access; the only thing it uses from `f` (the object created from `gzip.open`) is the `.fileno()` method, which gets the raw file descriptor, it doesn't know the file is compressed at all (`gzip.open` wraps that raw file descriptor in layers that perform the decompression on demand, but the low-level file descriptor is ignorant of all that).

To address some confusion: `mmap` doesn't get you magical I/O performance boosts. It's mostly useful if you:

1. Are performing random access on a file, and ideally
2. Are repeatedly reading from the file (often reaccessing the same pages you accessed earlier)

With stuff like JSON, random access is essentially useless; the file is likely UTF-8 text, so random access isn't even guaranteed to land at the beginning of a valid character, and even if was, the interpretation of character N in JSON is dependent on the interpretation of characters 0 through N-1 (are we in an object, an array, a string, etc.? Can't know without knowing the rest). So #1 doesn't apply.

Similarly, there's very little benefit to repeatedly reading the same JSON file over and over; deserialize it once and use that.

Point is, skip the `mmap` and just do:

```
import json
import gzip

with gzip.open("/home/test.json.gz", mode="r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

If you have a file with a format where random access makes sense, you still can't use the gzipped file directly (compressed data, like JSON, is context dependent; you need context from prior bytes to interpret the next). If you *must* use `mmap` for whatever reason, you need to decompress it first, e.g.:

```
import gzip
import shutil
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f_temp:  # Make an unnamed temporary file to use for mmap
    with gzip.open("/home/test.data.gz") as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, f_temp)  # Efficiently decompress from gzip to temp file
    f_temp.flush()  # Ensure no data stuck in user-mode buffers

    # Memory map temporary file and use it
    with mmap.mmap(f_temp.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as f_mmap:
        print(f_mmap.read())

    # mapping closed and deleted outside its with
# temporary file closed and deleted outside its with
```

In practice, if you'll be reusing this file a lot, I'd suggest just storing it uncompressed to avoid decompressing every time before use, but I figured I'd demonstrate how you could make something like this work in case your real use case demands it.

Comment: Note that it's possible to `mmap` the raw (compressed) data, then use `zlib.decompressobj` to do a lazy decompression as you go, feeding it data from the `mmap` object. It won't gain you anything at all (you still have to decompress from the beginning to end, and `gzip.open`'s file-like object does that for you under the covers), so I'm not going to detail the process; it won't speed up I/O, it won't save memory unless you rewrite JSON parsing from scratch, etc. Just don't do it.

Comment: Additional note: *If* you can open the file and do a little work before using it, you *may* benefit a bit from [using `os.posix_fadvise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.posix_fadvise) with the `SEQUENTIAL` or `WILLNEED` flag on the original fd after opening. It's highly unlikely to matter (reading a file through sequentially is pretty well optimized), but if there's a delay between open and use, the non-blocking bulk reads `WILLNEED` triggers in the background might make the eventual `read` calls to load the JSON run a little faster (the work to decompress limits the benefit).

Comment: @ ShadowRanger Thanks very much for the detailed explanation!!. This helped a lot